# Yii ajax call and session handling

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session, yii

I stucked in Yii, with an Ajax call "bug". The problem is, that i have to search by checkboxes, wich are stored in SESSION after hitting the search button.

After this, the keywords inserts into SESSION, and i want to print them in a tag-cloud. (with a cross in the corner -> delete this tag).
The removal of these tags is handled by an ajax call:

```
$(".tags a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var class1 = $(this).attr("class");
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
            $("#checkbox__"+id).removeAttr("checked");

jQuery.ajax({
        url: "recipe/removeFromSession",
        type: "POST",
        data: "id=" + class1+"&rcp="+id,
        dataType: "json",
        "success": function(data){
                    location.reload();
        },
        "error": function(xhr, status, error) {
                        var err = xhr.responseText;
                        alert(xhr.status);
         },
        "cache" : false,
    });
});
```

It calls the removeFromSession action:

```
public function actionRemoveFromSession() {
    $remove = intval($_POST['id']);

    unset($_SESSION['searchItems']['category'][$remove]);
    unset($_SESSION['recipeSearch']['category'][$_POST['rcp']]);

    echo json_encode($_SESSION);
}
```

The problem is that it doesn't unsets the value. It's still in the session. Any idea? (sorry for grammar mistakes)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

> Set your session:

```
Yii::app()->session['searchItems']['category'][$keyword] = "Any string";
```

> To unset session:

```
unset(Yii::app()->session['searchItems']['category'][$remove]);
```